# PCI passthrough strategy in Docker or oVirt

Tags: networking, docker, virtualization, pci, pass-through

We have to deploy a test system where a Docker container or a VM (oVirt 3.5) shares up to 4x 10GB network cards with other containers/VMs.

So far we are using just oVirt for this purpose but we would like to shift to a Dockerized system to save some resources on the machines.

Does anybody have some experience or suggestion?

Comment: This question is too broad and probably better for serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers are really just processes; it can run them each in a separate network namespace (the default) or let them use the host's network directly (`--net=host`).

If running in a separate network namespace then they won't have any access to the host's network cards; in the default config (`--net=bridge`) they are NAT networked via a Linux bridge, so if that matches your requirements, you're away.

[Link to Docker docs on networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/)